# Sub Rows Table using react table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

[image]

I want to make a table like this using React Hook Table. https://react-table.tanstack.com/

This is my columns

```js
const columns = React.useMemo(() => [
        {
            Header: 'Time',
            accessor: 'actual_time',
        },
        {
            Header: 'Author',
            accessor: 'author',
        },
        {
            Header: 'Transcript',
            accessor: 'trans',
        },
        {
            Header: 'Rating',
            accessor: 'rank',
        },
    ])
```

It is giving an error like

```js
Uncaught Error: Duplicate columns were found with ids: "trans" in the columns array above
    at useTable (useTable.js:262)
```

Please help me to structure `columns` and `data`

Comment: Why do you have two `trans` accessor? That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: Yea. Thanks. Now I get rid of the error. Now please tell me how to structure the data